# Reverse Concatenate an Email Address Field in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I am a business-to-Business merchant.  When I import orders from my shopping cart into my database, I want to determine if that customer is already in my dbase.  The way I would like to do it is by checking to see if the customer's email domain name is already on-record.

How do I do a reverse concatenate action on an email address.  I want to place **only what is after the "@" symbol of an email address** into a table field **using a query**?

(MS Access 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Mid([EmailAddress],InstrRev([EmailAddress],"@")+1)` in your `SELECT` statement